# Use the data of Apps list in the collection site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, external-list, data-connection

I created a list (external content type) with Visual Studio in an app within in site collection under Office 365 SharePoint.

However, this list is not visible in the site collection, (the app is in a special subsite). I would have wanted to connect it to another list by the lookup field column for example.

How is it possible to use data from a list set in a classic app as a SharePoint list?

Answer (score 1):

Just so we're clear on terminology - I'll call the site where you installed the app the Host Web and the site created for the app (i.e. the site containing your custom list) the App Web.

The App Web is a child site of the Host Web. But, the end-user functionality exposed by SharePoint and SharePoint Designer are designed to hide this site from the user. By design, users are only supposed to be able to use the internals of an App (e.g. lists, libraries) using the functionality provided to them by the App developer.

You can however, access the internals of the App Web from the Host Web using one of the developers APIs (i.e. Server Object Model, Client Object Model or REST API).

Comment: Thank you for this information, I suspected, not practical to consume data via the column with lookup services Server Object Model, Client Object Model or REST APIs